# Deploy Java Web in Tomcat Subfolder Using Reverse Proxy

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, nginx, dns

I'm having trouble deploying a Java Web project to Tomcat.

In localhost(development environment), I can deploy it successfully. I can access the project by visiting `http://localhost:8080/project`.

I tried to deploy it on server. Of course I can access the project using `http://server_ip:8080/project`.
As you see, the project is located in `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/project`.

When I using it with reverse proxy powered by Nginx. Here's the configuration of Nginx:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/project;
    }
}
```

Normally, I can visiting the project using `http://example.com` and nginx will fetch the content in `http://127.0.0.1:8080/project`. It does, but I have trouble getting static files.

I use `<c:url>` tag to load static files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/assets/css/style.css" />" />
```

when I access the website using `http://server_ip:8080/project`, everything works fine. And the value of href will be `/project/assets/css/style.css`.

But when I access the website using `http://example.com`, the value of href will still be `/project/assets/css/style.css`, so I'll get a 404 error. Because this URL means `/project/project/assets/css/style.css`. However, the file is located in `/assets/css/style.css`

Anyone can help me with the problem? Thx a lot.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in your JSTL tags, your Java webapp is rendering it's `<c:url...>` value on the server-side and it knows nothing about the proxy infront of it.  Have you tried changing it to a relative URL Instead?  Change it to `<c:url value="assets/css/style.css" />`, or use the `context` attribute of `<c:url/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a explicit `location` match as below:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location ^~ /project {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/project;
    }

    location ^~ / {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**Explaination:**
`location ^~ /project {}` (Note: does not work for regular expressions)

The `^~` results in a case sensitive match for the beginning of a request. This means `/project`, `/project/logo.jpg`, etc will all be matched. This also halts the location scanning as soon as a match is met.

Comment: When I restart nginx, I got this error message: `Restarting nginx daemon: nginxnginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: the error is quite obvious. Check in your NginX configuration for any repeat definition of `location '/'`